# Example code on MSDN site that called AdjustTokenPrivileges() failed with "Cannot enable the SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME privilege"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msdn

I attempted to run the C++ code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366531(v=vs.85).aspx, however, it failed with:

```
Cannot enable the SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME privilege;
please check the local policy.
```

My OS is Win7 x64.

Comment: The page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx lists the rights related to SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME privilege, and http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080909163655AAo09ab describes how to add this privilege.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the required group policy is disabled by default under Windows 7 x64.

**Step 1: Find the name of the group policy, in control panel, that matches SE_LOCK_MEMORY:**

The following page describes the group policy rights that are required for a process to enable SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME:

- [MSDN: Authorization Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then follow link to [Privilege Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Note: the column after "SE_LOCK_MEMORY" states "User Right: Lock pages in memory.". This is the name of the "Local Security Policy" that we want to set in the next step.

**Step 2: Set the group policy described as "Lock pages in memory":**

The following pages describe how to add the "SE_LOCK_MEMORY" privilege to a username by changing group policy:

- [MSDN: Enable the Lock Pages in Memory Option (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190730.aspx#CommunityContent)
- [Yahoo: enable group policy for SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080909163655AAo09ab)

Note: You must reboot for this new policy to take effect (something that is not mentioned on the MSDN help page).